# Google App engine database

Tags: android, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I want to create mysql database in google cloud app engine(Google cloud sql) and fetch data in android application how to create? any suggestion or example for refer to me.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible) page may help you. Note that you can use Firebase for that.